# jQuery - Plugin generates an error "this.x is not a function"

Tags: function, plugins

I used the [doc](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) to create a basic plugin for myself but i cannot make it work for some reason.
My goal is to create a plugin to make any element draggable.
Here is my code :

```
var continues = true;
var elementPosition;
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.dragIt = function() {
    this.mousedown(function(i){
        elementPosition = this.position();
        continues = true;
        initialCursorX = i.pageX;
        initialCursorY = i.pageY;
        $(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
        if(continues == true) 
        {
        this.css({
           left:  elementPosition.left + e.pageX - initialCursorX,
           top:   elementPosition.top + e.pageY - initialCursorY,
        });
        }
        });
    });

this.mouseup(function(){
continues = false;
});
}}( jQuery ));

$('#square').dragIt();
```

Everytime I trigger the mousedown event on the #square div I got an error : "this.position is not a function".
What's wrong ?

EDIT : Note that it perfectly works if I do it directly without using the plugin.